# Is it possible to access Windows ESE from Java?

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

Windows ships with the Extensible Storage Engine (ESE), see [MSDN ESE doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269259%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx). I'm wondering if anyone is aware if Java's native Windows file system APIs support this or if there's a JNI based project that supports using it. My Googling has not turned up anything in this regard.

Comment: Do you want to use it to store your data? If yes, don't use it if your code is targetting below Windows Vista. Use `SQLite` instead. Because it is slowed and not fully support unicode.

Comment: @Putta Its a long story but I'm looking for atomic file system access on Windows Server 2008 when changing multiple files. Microsoft discourages transactional NTFS and suggests ESE.  Using a traditional DB is too slow for this particular application. ESE appears to offer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) with (esent.dll) windows API in Java to access all functions supported by the Extensible Storage Engine.
I've tried this and it worked for me.